# FullCalendar no refetch events

Tags: fullcalendar

I have worked with fullcalendar smoothly for a while, now I feel the need to implement some changes.
I need to filter the events, this has been helpful http://jsfiddle.net/QMyFu/337/, but I can not reset the filters and redisplay all events,

javascript code:

```
$('#boton').click(function(){
$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'refetchEvents' );
});
```

html code:

```
<button id="boton">Reload</button>
```

here I made a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pablop22/eT26Q/2/

any suggestions are welcome

Pablo

Answer (score 1):

I answer to myself, updating events is performed when events get json from a script, in this case to be within the page, the update was not performed